# Laravel fortify doesn't set status=verification-link-sent after registration

Tags: laravel, fortify

I'm using Fortify with Laravel 8.

Email verification works fine except for one thing: When the email verification link is automatically sent *immediately after registration*, the session('status') value is not set to 'verification-link-sent' (or anything else) and thus the subsequent view doesn't know what is happening. The status is, however, correctly set to 'verification-link-sent' in *all other instances* when the email verification link is indeed sent.

Question A: How can I change Fortify such that session('status')='verification-link-sent' is set immediately after registration? Or, is there some other way to detect that the email verification process is happening after registration?

Question B: Maybe I should be asking this instead: How can I set flash data in general when using Fortify?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I solved it by adding the following to the routes / web.php file:

```
Route :: post ('/ email / verification-notification', function (Request $ request) {
     $ request-> user () -> sendEmailVerificationNotification ();

     return back () -> with ('status', 'verification-link-sent');
}) -> middleware (['auth', 'throttle: 6,1']) -> name ('verification.send');
```

Comment: Hi, Roberto. Please format your code examples in a code block for clarity ([see docs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)) and watch out for whitespace/typos.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but solved it in a slightly different way.  The short version is that I added a piece of middleware to handle it.  Fortify's internal design is to invoke the sendEmailVerificationNotification from within the RegisteredUserController setup, and this solution leaves all that architecture in place.

Specifically:

1. Create the middleware file on the command line:
   `php artisan make:middleware NotifyEmailVerificationSent`
2. Update `/app/Http/Kernel.php` to register the new middleware, and give it a convenient name:

```php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    // existing code

    // we're adding to this array
    protected $routeMiddleware = [

        //existing entries

        'verification.sent' => \App\Http\Middleware\NotifyEmailVerificationSent::class,
    ];
    
    // existing code
}
```

3. Copy the POST /register route from `/vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php` to `/routes/web.php` and modify it to use the new middleware.  I also included the route's grouping information.
   The new entry in `web.php` looks like this:

```php
// Over-riding Fortify's POST /register to include a notice about the emailed verification link
Route::group(['middleware' => config('fortify.middleware', ['web'])], function () {
    if (Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
            Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['guest:' . config('fortify.guard'), 'verification.sent']);
    }
});
```

4. Write the new middleware.  It simply flashes the status message to the session after the response does the rest of its business.

```php
class NotifyEmailVerificationSent
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $request->session()->flash('status', 'verification-link-sent');

        return $response;
    }
}
```